# Do we need the "data" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms, retagging

The [data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) tag has quite a few questions (>250), but it seems to me the tag is redundant. (It also has no tag wiki, which is usually a sign, at this stage in the site's life, that the tag shouldn't exist.)

Many of them are better covered (and often already tagged) as [dataset](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dataset), [database](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) etc. Questions about how to manipulate and transform data in some way -- say, interpolating it -- would be better tagged according to type of transformation, e.g. [interpolation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpolation).

It would be quite a bit of retagging / tag deletion work to get that done. What do people think?

Comment: Related discussion about low quality tags: [Possible tag merge: table, matrix, array](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1221/4330).

Comment: In my opinion, there are also advantages to keeping low quality tags. They can be an opportunity for new users to apply a tag, without doing a "harmful" mistag, like for example applying bugs. Nobody has to use the data tag in a search if they don't want to and the presence of a tag like data or table in the list of tags for a question is only mildly distracting. It can always be removed if there are already 5 tags and a nicer tag does not fit. Of course when a user tags as data when dataset would have been better, that is a missed opportunity, but again people can edit.

Comment: I suppose a major disadvantage of keeping the tag would be that it can show up in the [tags list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags), where it is currently at the second page.

Comment: How could questions related to scientific data be tagged?  I didn't see a good alternative, and I think such a tag might be helpful to some site visitors.  Disclosure: not to me personally, though.  (Now the difference between the "image" and "imagedata" tags is inscrutable to me.  That's a separate issue, but I happened to notice looking at the various data tags.)

Answer (score 9):

After looking through the list of [data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data)-tagged questions, I agree with Verbeia.  Overly general tags like [data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) are essentially void of information, thus they do more harm than good.

I suggest [blacklisting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19018/164803) this tag to get rid of it for good.  Otherwise it will keep coming back.

Would blacklisting auto-remove it from all those 250 questions?